# Adding Event Listeners to Buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to Actionscript and I am creating a simple addition game where the player will click on numbers 1 through 9 on the bottom of the screen to solve an addition problem. Should I create individual buttons or movieclips on the bottom?

How do I add event listeners to the buttons/movieclips to be able to tell if the player clicked the second button as opposed to other buttons on the screen. Thank you!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty similar to Ronnie's solution (I was almost finished this so had to post) and it is tested:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

var buttonCount = 9;
var buttonSize = 50;

var button:MovieClip;
var label:TextField;

for (var i:int = 0; i < buttonCount; i ++)
{
    // Create a new MovieClip
    button = new MovieClip();

    // We'll use this in the event handler to identify which button was clicked
    button.id = i + 1;

    // Draw the background in the graphics prop of the MovieClip
    button.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
    button.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, buttonSize, buttonSize);

    // Add event listener
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.clickHandler);

    // Position the button
    button.x = i * (buttonSize + 20); // Add some spacing
    button.y = stage.stageHeight - buttonSize - 10;

    // Add the button to the stage
    addChild(button);   

    // Create the label for the button
    label = new TextField();
    label.text = button.id.toString();
    label.selectable = false;
    label.multiline = false;
    label.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    label.setTextFormat(new TextFormat('Arial', 12, 0, true));

    // Position the label in the centre of the button
    label.x = (buttonSize - label.width) / 2;
    label.y = (buttonSize - label.height) / 2;

    // Add the label to the button MovieClip
    button.addChild(label);
}

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Button clicked:", event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make a single movie clip with a text field in it. For example, I have a movie clip (with a linkage name of `NumClip`) and a dynamic text field inside called `numText` (Be sure to embed numerals or whatever other characters you need). Then a simple for loop should do the trick.

```
var maxNum:Number = 9;

for (var i:int = 1; i <= maxNum; i++)
{
    var clip:NumClip = new NumClip();
    clip.x = i * (clip.width + 5);
    clip.y = 50;
    clip.id = i;
    clip.numText.text = String(i);
    clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numClick);
    addChild(clip);
}

function numClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("You clicked number " + e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it looks good to me and should do the trick